# Laravel 5.5 - Horizon custom job tags for queued event listener

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-horizon

In the [documentation for Horizon](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/horizon), it mentions that custom tags can be added to queued event listeners. However, I can't find any way to pull in my event instance containing the data I need. The example given uses type-hinting to pull the relevant model out of the service container and assigns it to an instance variable in the constructor, then uses that instance variable in the `tags()` method to get data about the particular model instance being operated on.

When doing this in a queued event listener though, it doesn't work. In fact, the constructor doesn't ever seem to be called at all, due to the model being serialized and 're-hydrated' when it comes to be executed. So type-hinting in the constructor does nothing, and `tags()` appears to be called before `handle()`, so I can't get access to the event object I'm listening to.

Does anyone know how I can get event information in a tag in this situation?

**Update:**

Event called in controller:

```
event(new PostWasCreated($user, $post));
```

Event *PostWasCreated*:

```
<?php
namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use App\User;
use App\Post;

class PostWasCreated
{
    use InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $user;
    public $post;

    public function __construct(User $user, Post $post)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->post = $post;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
    }
}
```

Listener *PostWasCreatedNotificationSend*:

```
<?php
namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\PostWasCreated;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class PostWasCreatedNotificationSend implements ShouldQueue
{
    protected $event;
    public $queue = 'notifications'; // Adds queue name

    public function __construct(PostWasCreated $event)
    {
      $this->event = $event;
      // Does NOT add queue tag
      $this->queueTags = ['post: ' . $this->event->post->id];
    }

    public function tags()
    {
      return $this->queueTags;
    }

    public function handle(PostWasCreated $event)
    {
      // handle event here...
    }
}
```

The issue is `$this->queueTags` never gets assigned, so there are no tags in Horizon for this queued listener... (queue name show up though, but we need tags as well).

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the class that get's actually queued is the [CallQueuedListener](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Events/CallQueuedListener.php) and not the listener you define (see [Dispatcher](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php#L390) for reference). Therefore I think that either the documentation is misleading or the missing functionality should be considered a bug.

Comment: Horizon pulls the event out of the `CallQueuedListener` job to look for any tags. It's hard to understand what's happening from this description. Can you please show the code for the event you're trying to enqueue? Does it exhibit the `SerializesModels` trait?

Comment: @CyRossignol Sorry for the delay, I posted the updated code where it is reproducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Horizon collects any tags *before* even pushing a job onto a queue, so we can't rely on any values that a job doesn't know before it executes. In this case, the job knows the `User` and `Post` because we pass them to initialize the event.

For queued listeners, the tagging system checks for tags on both the event object and the listener class. As described in the question, there's no way to set tags with dynamic data on the listener because the handler executes *after* Horizon pops the job off of the queue. We can only declare static tags on a listener that Horizon will merge* with the tags on the event:

```
class PostWasCreatedNotificationSend implements ShouldQueue 
{
    ...
    public function tags() 
    {
        return [ 'listener:' . static::class, 'category:posts' ];
    }
}
```

With the event object, Horizon attempts to automatically generate tags for any Eloquent model members. For example, Horizon will create the following tags for a `PostWasCreated` event:

- `$event->user` → `App\User:<id>`
- `$event->post` → `App\Post:<id>`

We can override this behavior and tell Horizon which tags to set for the event by defining a `tags()` method like above:

```
class PostWasCreated 
{
    ...
    public function tags() 
    {
        return [ 'post:' . $this->post->id ];
    }
}
```

Note that, at the time of writing, Horizon will not automatically create tags for models if the event ***or*** the listener provide tags manually.

> The issue is `$this->queueTags` never gets assigned, so there are no tags in Horizon for this queued listener... (queue name show up though, but we need tags as well).

Horizon doesn't create tags for every property; the automatic tagging only works for those that contain Eloquent models (and generally not for a listener).

---

*If the event is also used for broadcasting (it implements `ShouldBroadcast`), the additional job created to publish the message does not inherit any tags provided by the listener.

Comment: Thanks for getting back on this, it works as you described, when the tags are set in the event and the listener is queued. It's weird though that for Notifications, the dynamic tags work, just not on the event listener itself. I thought it should work on Notifications, Jobs, and Event Listeners, so still a bit baffled as to why it works for notification just not event listener dynamically :/

Comment: @Wonka - Let's see if I'm following what you're saying... A `Job`, `Event`, or `Notification`, and any models or data on them, all exist before going into the queue when Horizon assigns the tags. However, an event *listener* doesn't contain any data... it consumes it from the item popped off of the queue, so we can't use any of that data in the listener's tags. Did I understand what you were asking?

Comment: I believe so yes. I specially tried with an event which `SerializedModels` and normal (non queued) listener, which has a handle method that fires off a queued `Notification`. In the queued `Notification`, the dynamic tags work. I updated the last piece of code for the listener in my question to match what the working dynamic `Notification` working tags look like. Basically updated the constructor, and added tags method, but that setup doesn't work on listener, only on notification (notification uses `Queueable`). So I am not sure if it's a bug or if I am doing something wrong..

Comment: @Wonka - I agree--it's confusing at first... I wouldn't call it a bug...more of a limitation in the current version of Horizon. Listeners work a bit differently that the other kinds of jobs because the queue system resolves them from the container (the others are recreated from serialized data stored in the queue), so we can't inject models/data via the constructor. We need to rely on the event tags for tagging queued listener jobs with that dynamic data.